# SOAP Action issue when calling WCF Service in Perl (SOAP Lite)

Tags: wcf, perl, soap, soaplite

Using Perl (SOAP Lite), I am trying to call a wcf web service where the SOAPAction name (ProcessMessage) is different to the Envelope/Body/**Request** element name (Request) within the soap envelope body. How can a specify a different SOAPAction and Envelope->Body->Request element name? I cannot change the web service.

Here is an example of the SOAP Message I'm trying to replicate and I've highlighed the two areas I'm trying to specify/control independently.

```
<HttpRequest>
  <Method>POST</Method>
  <QueryString></QueryString>
  <WebHeaders>
<Content-Length>1245</Content-Length>
<Content-Type>text/xml; charset=utf-8</Content-Type>
<Accept-Encoding>gzip, deflate</Accept-Encoding>
<Expect>100-continue</Expect>
<Host>virscwapp01f1.sdpcsf.sdp.net.nz</Host>
<SOAPAction>"urn:sdp:manager:100818.ProfileScopeServiceContract.ProcessMessage"</SOAPAction>
</WebHeaders>
</HttpRequest>
 <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
   <ActivityId CorrelationId="0d113c44-878d-40c4-bc3d-37a1ac9a693e" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ActivityId>
    <To s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://[hostname]/ProfileManager/100818/ProfileManager.svc</To>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">urn:manager:100818.ProfileScopeServiceContract.ProcessMessage</Action>
 </s:Header>
 <s:Body>
     <Request xmlns="urn:managerrequestmanager:100818" xmlns:a="urn:manager:requestmanager" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <a:Payload i:type="b:Organisation" xmlns:b="urn:manager:contract:110308">
    <b:OrganisationUnitId>OrgId</b:OrganisationUnitId>
    <b:OrganisationDescription i:nil="true"></b:OrganisationDescription>
  </a:Payload>
  <a:ProcessingInstruction xmlns:b="urn:manager:contract:common:100818">
    <b:Action>GetOrganisationById</b:Action>
    <b:Strategy>
      <b:Name i:nil="true"></b:Name>
      <b:Paging i:nil="true"></b:Paging>
      <b:SearchCriteria i:nil="true"></b:SearchCriteria>
    </b:Strategy>
    <b:Meta i:nil="true"></b:Meta>
  </a:ProcessingInstruction>
</Request>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Here is an example of the Perl script I am using

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package main;
use SOAP::Lite +trace;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common;

# Variables
my $url = 'http://[hostname]/ProfileManager/100818/ProfileManager.svc?wsdl';
my $url_debug = 'http://localhost:11040/Service1.svc?wsdl';
my $uri = 'urn:::profilemanager:profilemanagerrequestmanager:100818';

my $soap = SOAP::Lite
-> ns( 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', 'xsi' )
-> ns( 'urn:::profilemanager:requestmanager', 'a' )
-> ns( 'urn:::profilemanager:contract:110308', 'b'  )
-> uri($uri)
-> on_action( sub { join '.', 'urn:::profilemanager:requestmanager:100818.ProfileScopeServiceContract', $_[1] } )
-> proxy($url);


my $method = SOAP::Data->name('ProcessMessage')
->attr({xmlns => 'urn:::profilemanager:profilemanagerrequestmanager:100818'});


my @params = ( SOAP::Data->type("b:Organisation")->name("a:Payload")->value(
\SOAP::Data->value(
SOAP::Data->name("b:OrganisationUnitId")->value(""),
SOAP::Data->name("b:OrganisationDescription")->attr( { 'xsi:nil' => "true" } )  
    )
  ),
   SOAP::Data->name("a:ProcessingInstruction")->value(
   \SOAP::Data->value(
     SOAP::Data->name("b:Action")->value("GetOrganisationById"),
SOAP::Data->name("b:Strategy")->value(
    \SOAP::Data->value(
          SOAP::Data->name("b:Name")->attr( { 'xsi:nil' => "true" } ),
     SOAP::Data->name("b:Paging")->attr( { 'xsi:nil' => "true" } ),
     SOAP::Data->name("b:SearchCriteria")->attr( { 'xsi:nil' => "true" } )
     )
      ),
      SOAP::Data->name("b:Meta")->attr( { 'xsi:nil' => "true" } )
)
)
);

print $soap->call($method => @params)->result;
```

Dont pay too much attention to my namespaces as I've removed portions of them.

Comment: I believe someone has answer my question here but as I'm new to Perl I dont understand the answer. [link] http://code.activestate.com/lists/perl-xml/8922/ [link]

Comment: Okay I worked out the solution myself

Comment: For reference, it would be good to share the solution in case anyone else runs into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this to make SOAP::Lite work with WCF:

```
my $serviceInterface = 'IMyWcfServiceInterface';

# Setup Network Connection
my $service = SOAP::Lite
    ->ns( $namespace, $namespacePrefix )
    ->proxy( $server, credentials => [ "$host:$port", $realm, $username => $password ] )
    ->on_action( sub {
        my $action = sprintf( '%s$serviceInterface/%s', @_ );
        print( "action: '$action'\n" );
        return $action;
    } );

my $response = $service->MyServiceFunction()
```

In your case, you seem to want the action to be: `urn:sdp:manager:100818.ProfileScopeServiceContract.ProcessMessage`, so you should probably be able to just use:

```
...
    ->on_action( 'urn:sdp:manager:100818.ProfileScopeServiceContract.ProcessMessage' )
...
```

Perl the [pom documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~phred/SOAP-Lite-1.06/lib/SOAP/Lite.pm#METHODS):

```
on_action(callback)

    $client->on_action(sub { qq("$_[0]") });
```

> Triggered when the transport object sets up the SOAPAction header for an HTTP-based 
>   call. The default is to set the header to the string, uri#method, in which URI is the
>   value set by the uri method described earlier, and method is the name of the method
>   being called. When called, the routine referenced (or the closure, if specified as in
>   the example) is given two arguments, uri and method, in that order.
>
> .NET web services usually expect / as separator for uri and method. To change SOAP::Lite's 
>    behaviour to use uri/method as SOAPAction header, use the following code:

```
    $client->on_action( sub { join '/', @_ } );
```